# What is this spacecraft in the Elementary OS default wallpaper?

Tags: wallpaper

In the current Elementary OS version, there is a default wallpaper like this: 
[image]

My question is: what is the spacecraft in this photo? Is it Soyuz or SpaceX Dragon? And what was it doing at that time?

Please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This wallpaper was introduced with Elementary OS Loki. This photo is by SpaceX. I'm not sure what it was doing there. But this is SpaceX's Dragon and it's wallpaper was uploaded to [Collection of wallpapers for elementary OS - GitHub](https://github.com/elementary/wallpapers) 2 years ago with the name "Photo by SpaceX.jpg". The closest article to this I've found is: [SpaceX's Dragon Capsule May Be Contaminating the ISS | WIRED](https://www.wired.com/story/a-spacex-delivery-capsule-may-be-contaminating-the-iss/).